# GSM/GPRS board sim800c "AT+CTTS=?" returns "ERROR"

Tags: at-command

I got a sim800c board and as per its design document and AT commands manual, it is supposed to support Text to Speech (TTS). But as I tried, all TTS AT commands returned "ERROR". Anyone knows why?

AT+CTTSPARAM=?
ERROR
AT+CTTS=?
ERROR

Comment: I suspect that those commands aren't actually supported by SIM800c,  as the AT command guide is defined for a large set of models. But I actually wasn't able to find evidence of this suspect in the guide. I'll go on searching. In the meanwhile you could find useful [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60994232/11336762) and [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56914146/11336762)

Comment: To get a list of all the commands a modem/phone supports, you can run `AT+CLAC` (or `AT*` on phones with Ericsson/ST-Ericsson origin).