# Make a call through GSM A7672s module and play an audio file in it

Tags: gsm, at-command, gsmcomm

I am working on a project and this is my objective - when something's detected, we make a call to a number and an audio should be played over the call alerting the user. I am not exactly sure how to achieve this with AT commands.

What I have tried:

1. I first tried to transfer the file. Sucess. But I could not play it and test it since I don't have a speaker I could connect.

```
AT+FSCD=C:                      \\ Changing to C dir
AT+CFTRANRX="c:/r1.amr",255     \\ Transfer to r1.amr
-- hex of r1.amr --
```

2. Make a call

```
ATD*\number\*                      \\ Making a call to the number;
AT+CDTAM=1                         \\ Setting mode to 'Remote path'
AT+CCMXPLAY="c:/r1.amr",1,255      \\ Playing the audio file
ATH                                \\ Hang up call
```

My doubts:
I am new to working with AT commands and GSM, so please clarify the below:

1. I have no idea if I should be using the CDTAM at all. Saw that it was about TTS. But no success even if I try without it. (Also AT+CTTS=? returns ERROR so I guess my module doesn't have this functionality)
2. What is the 'remote path' and 'local path' when playing a audio file?
3. Is my sequence of commands right?
4. What should be the right commands plus their sequence if I want to achieve my objective?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

References:

1. Manual - [https://www.ktron.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/A76XX-Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.06-4.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com)
2. Similar question - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909155/gsm-sim800c-text-to-speech-audio-stream/60994232#60994232](https://stackoverflow.com)